# how to include a href tag in mail body?

Tags: grails

I am using grails mail plugin to send email as shown below. how can i include link in body?

```
mailService.sendMail{
                    delegate.to em
                    delegate.subject params['subject']
                    delegate.body "${params['body']} \n\nPlease click <a href='${l}'> Unsubscribe </a> to unsubscribe from the list."
                }
```

In the received email it is received as

```
Please click <a href='https://ne-palmr.com/road/subscriptionCancellation/cancelSubscription?email=test%40gmail.com&from=979&t=d4007eb1ec361d8c3ec82f9525af2d08'> Unsubscribe </a> to unsubscribe from the list.
```

whereas the expected result is

```
Please click Unsubscribe to unsubscribe from the list.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will duplicate Slack answer here: You need to change `body` to `html`.
Also you don't need to use `delegate` before methods